# Divide one HTML page into multiple pages of A4

Tags: html, spring-mvc, itext, thymeleaf

I have an HTML page and I need to show the page in multiple portions. When user clicks next, the next portion of the page is shown to the user. I am using spring-mvc, Itext and thymleaf.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Or is there anyway I can convert PDF to html using Itext?

Comment: Use bxslider. You can refer to http://bxslider.com/

Comment: I have only one HTML, how to divide that?

Comment: Please check Step-2 in the link above. You can assign each of the subpage's content to the slider. For controlling the transitions and other slider features refer to http://bxslider.com/options

Comment: I don't understand why iText is mentioned as a tag. Your question (and the answers given to it) clearly indicate that you're talking about HTML only. The *Or is there any way I can convert PDF to HTML using iText* doesn't rime with the rest of the question. That question is (of course) unanswerable unless you are talking about a Tagged PDF. Are you?

Answer (score 1):

There's a js solution only written as an answer here [Splitting a long page into a number of pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061393/splitting-a-long-page-into-a-number-of-pages)

a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/XwUuA/

to have it splitting to A4 just change the dimension in the css

```
#paginate{width:200px;height:290px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #414141;}
```

It might not be perfect depending on your page, but I find it a very nice script targeting just what you need

Comment: Thanks.. But hard coding the height will not have any effect if say user has zoomed?

Comment: Yes, that's the "might not be perfect" part. Perhaps you can make an addition and establish are relation between the height and zoom. I was wondering if I were to make an answer a comment instead, but went for a response as I think the original answer deserves attention

Answer (score 0):

when i need a easy way to change page content in single page from multiple pages i use this:`

```
 <a href="site1" class="logo">link</a>
 <a href="site2">link</a>
 <a href="site3">link</a>
```

Jquery

```
$("main").load("site1.html");
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("main").load($(this).attr('href')+".html");
});
});
```

What the script does is getting content from the link you click on. So you would need additional pages with your content inside.  :) 
example on your site names for your content:
site1.html site2.html site3.html
pretty simple. Just ask if you need more help i will set up an example and zip it
to you.

Comment: and ofc. you can just have next / prev buttons instead of site links ;D